# NX package is installed globally but i dont see it in the npm global list

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nrwl-nx, nx.dev

I'm having problems using globally installed [NX](https://nx.dev/concepts/more-concepts/global-nx) packags.

I run `npm -g nx` in the command line, the command line display a message that `added 8 packages, removed 18 packages, and changed 107 packages in 3m`.

There is no error, no warning

I have confirmed it is installed by using `npm list -g` command, but i dont see the NX package at all.

Here is an image that display what happens:

[image: NX-CMD]